# Difference between plot.class_name and ggplot.class_name

Tags: r, generics, ggplot2, plot, r-package

In developing an R package, in order to extend the generic plot function, what is the difference between `plot.class_name` and `ggplot.class_name`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
add_values <- function(a, b){
  
  out <- list()
  class(out) <- "myclass"
  
  c <- a + b 
  
  out$a <- a
  out$b <- b
  out$c <- c
  
  return(out)
}

plot.myclass <- function(x, ...){
  cat("Called by plot.")
  plot(x$a,x$b)
}

ggplot.myclass <- function(x, ...){
  cat("Called by ggplot.")
  plot(x$b,x$a)
}

a <- seq(0,10,0.01)
b <- a^2
x <- add_values(a,b)
plot(x) # Prints out: Called by plot.
ggplot(x) # Prints out: Called by ggplot.
```

For a simple test, it seems both of them work fine. I prefer to use ggplot inside the package. There are a couple of options:

1. Developing two separate methods for `plot.myclass` and `ggplot.myclass`
2. Use `ggplot` inside `plot.myclass` then `plot(object)` will return ggplot results.
3. Use `ggplot` inside `ggplot.myclass` and do not support `plot(object)` command.

Does CRAN have any restriction on using any of these options?

Comment: ggplot2 provides an autoplot generic intended for packages that want to have their own ggplot2 graphics class, e.g. autoplot.myclass. If you want to have your own classic graphics class then use plot.myclass.  The zoo package supports classic, lattice and ggplot2 graphics and has zoo methods for plot, xyplot and autoplot if you need examples.

Comment: I'm not aware of any restrictions in CRAN and it is pretty common that the `plot.myclass` method prints a (gg)plot. The difference between `plot` and `ggplot` is that `plot` always prints the output, whereas ggplot2 doesn't necessarily. See also: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#best-practices-for-common-tasks